# Which database structure is efficient? One table with 10,000 records or 1000 tables with 10 records?

Tags: sql

We at college are making an application to generate PDF document from Excel sheet records using Java SE. I have though about two approaches to design the database. In one approach, there will be one table that will contain a lot of records (50K every year). In other approach, there will be a lot of tables created (1000 every year) at runtime and each table will contain max 50 records. 
Which approach is efficient comparatively considering better overall time performance?

Comment: You create the tables at runtime? Ideally, your schema should be fixed, so the single table approach is probably best. If it's properly indexed, there won't be any significant performance hit.

Comment: What is the goal of this table?

Comment: @Xophmeister Can you explain or redirect me to a link which has more information about 'indexing'
@ FabienTheSolution The table is used to generate pdf marksheet using records by concatenating a few tables. In second approach, each table is a class name with 50 student record

Comment: @user2754552 [You can start here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

Comment: Imagine a new library has a pile of 1 million books.  They decide to store the books by genre, then alphabetically by author's last name, that's like a clustered index in some databases, the physical order of the items is established.  Non-clustered indexes are more like pointers, maybe you want to find the 10 newest books, the storage order won't help you with that, but a list of books by publish date would.  Indexes on db's are like that, they make finding individual items very quick.  Just a rough analogy, but hope it helps.

Comment: @GoatCO Your analogy somewhat matches my situation too :) If I could achieve indexing by a batch's semester, the issue of time searching will be eliminated.

Comment: Date fields are often worth indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When building a relational database the basic rule would be to **avoid redundancy**.

Look over your data and try to separate things that tend to repeat. If you notice a column or a group of columns that repeat across multiple entries create a new table for them. This way you will achieve the best performance when querying.

Otherwise, if the values are unique across the entries just keep the minimum number of tables.

You should just look for some [**design rules**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for relational databases. You will find some examples as well.

Answer (score 8):

Multiple tables of identical structure almost never makes sense.

Databases are designed to have many records in few tables.

Answer (score 1):

50K records is not "a lot" of records.  You don't specify what database you will be using, but most commercial-grade databases can handle many, many millions of records in a table. 
This is assuming you have proper indexes, etc.  If you have to keep creating tables for you application, then there is something wrong with your design, and you need to re-think that.

Comment: I am using sqlite. I can switch to a more efficient one if you could suggest one. Searching time could be critical in this case (shouldn't exceed 10 seconds on an old system like P4, will not be made for server).

Comment: Looking at their limits page - http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html  I don't think it will be a problem regarding size.  Can't comment on performance.

Answer (score 0):

50k records is not much for a database. If it's all the same type of data (same structure), it belongs in the same table. Only if size and speed becomes an issue you should consider splitting up the data over multiple tables (or more likely: different servers).